# Scala : No Json serializer found for type Object. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type

Tags: json, scala

I have two functions, one returns a single user based on his id and the second returns multiple users based on their ids,

The first function return this array : `User[id=1, name="name1", lastName= "lastname1"]`

The second function return this: `[User [id=1, name="name1", lastName= "lastname1"], User [id=2, name="name2", lastName= "lastname2"]]`

My first scala function is as follow and the json is well returned and i have no error:

```
 Option(Try(id.toLong) match {
     case Success(id) => User.getUserById(1)
    }) match {  
      case Some(user) => Ok(Json.toJson(user) )
      case None => NotFound
    }
```

But my second scala function returns an error (see my title) :

```
Option(Try(id.toList) match {
     case Success(id) => User.getUsersByIds(id) // id list is 1,2
    }) match {  
      case Some(users) => Ok(Json.toJson(users) )
      case None => NotFound
    }
```

My getUsersByIds function :

```
 public static synchronized ArrayList<User> getUsersByIds(List usersIDs) {


        String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID IN" + usersIDs) ;

        ArrayList<User> userList = getArrayList(strSQL);

    return userList
    }
```

How can i return the right json format to get all my users ? I need to add a map ? if so, how ?

thank you

Comment: Give the def of getUsersById

Comment: You mean post the code of getUsersByIds ?

Comment: We would at least need the return type of the `getUsersByIds` function. I'm asuming it's some subclass of `Iterable[User]`. If so, is this User class a case class?

Comment: it returns an arrayList. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

By default, Play only has serializers for the Scala collection.
This should make it work:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

Json.toJson(users.asScala)
```

Comment: Hi n1r3, i have an error :value toSeq is not a member of java.util.ArrayList[User]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found it : .asScala solves the problem